# How to change terminal in Qt Creator?

Tags: macos, qt, qt-creator

How to set iterm2 as a terminal in Qt Creator? When I click on "open terminal here" it opens the Mac OS default terminal. How could I change it to open e.g. `iterm2` instead?

[image: open terminal here]

Comment: This is a decent question, in fact! The `Environment/System/Terminal` setting exists in the Preferences dialog, but doesn't allow free-form entry. I'll have to check how Qt Creator selects the terminals to populate this list.

Comment: Qt Creator 4.1 (Ubuntu) allows to change `Environment/System/Terminal` to any value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing you are on OSX, you can use the solution I [posted here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/264772/qt-creator-and-iterm2#answer-287649). You can create a new script to open a new iTerm2 window, then execute a command/script.

For convinience, here is a copy of my answer:

---

> First, create a script (let's say `~/newiTerm.sh`) and put the following content
>
> ```
> #! /bin/bash
>
> # ugly escaping: for apple script \ and " need to be escaped, whereas %q takes care of all bash escaping
>
> declare -a args
> mydir=`pwd`
> mydir=$(printf '%q' "$mydir")
> mydir="${mydir//\\/\\\\}"
> args[0]="cd ${mydir//\"/\\\"};"
> for a in "$@" ; do
>     x=$(printf '%q ' "$a")
>     x="${x//\\/\\\\}"
>     args[${#args[@]}]="${x//\"/\\\"}"
> done
> mArgs=${args[@]:0}
>
> osascript <<EOF
> set cdScript to "$mArgs"
> tell application "iTerm2"
>     set newWindow to (create window with default profile)
>     tell newWindow
>         select
>         set _session to current session
>         tell _session
>             write text cdScript
>         end tell
>     end tell
> end tell
> ```
>
> Then, go to **Qt Preferences** ( `⌘,` ) > **Environment** > **System** > **Terminal** and set the value to `~/newiTerm.sh`

Cheers

*Note* - Make sure you have permission for the shell script. 
You need to give proper permission, something like this `chmod a+x  ~/newiTerm.sh`. Otherwise, QT won't able to run it.

[image: Sceenshot of setting window]

Comment: Where exactly I need to change. I am not able see that ` Environment > Terminal ' option

Comment: Yeah sorry it is in the **System** tab

Comment: Where I can find the docs to create a new tab instead of a new window?

Comment: not runs. also I can't run it within a terminal with error `153:159: syntax error: Expected “,” but found class name. (-2741)`